# Sending custom requests through iCloud private relay

Tags: icloud, safari, vpn, proxy, icloud-plus

I'm asking myself if it is possible to send custom requests (including custom headers) via the iCloud private relay, as I could do it with a normal VPN ?

If not, is there any program made to send custom requests from safari such as chromedriver does with chrome, in the goal to pass by the private relay ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Asking one question per question is highly encouraged here. Get your first question answered authoritatively and then ask a follow on (linked if necessary) question is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

In beta - iCloud Private Relay is transparent and offers no configuration options. What differentiates Apple’s offering from the others I have evaluated is there are two levels of indirection where Apple would hopefully strip away custom requests by design.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212614

The technical / developer level details how it uses UDP / QUIC are also documented online:

- https://developer.apple.com/support/prepare-your-network-for-icloud-private-relay/

Perhaps if you [explained your end goal in using custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58721114/475228), we could elaborate more.